# Scope of each on rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to build a view that will list the parents and related children

Ex:
Passport has many Visas

I want to list information about the passport and the visas that the passport has.

So I have

```
<% @passport_list.each do |passport| %>
   # passportFields
   <% passport.visas.each do |visa| %>
       <%= t.text_field :visa_type %>   
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the error

```
undefined method `visa_type' for #Passport:0x000000091b8b28
```

It looks like rails is trying to find the property `visa_type` for passport, instead of in visa. How does the scope work within `each`? Can I force it to access `visa_type` from `visa`?

Comment: why u need <%= t.text_field :visa_type %>  ? You can use just <%= visa.visa_type %> to display  the value. If you want to show some form then you have to use nested forms.

Comment: sure @madyrockss , it's inside a form, I have omitted that information and if I use like that <%= visa.visa_type %> it works, how do I transform that into a text_field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) form helper. This will allow you to create fields for the relevant `visa` attributes. Replace your code sample with the following, and you should be all set.

```
<% @passport_list.each do |passport| %>
  # passportFields
  <% t.fields_for :visas do |visa_fields| %>
    <%= visa_fields.text_field :visa_type %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also iterate over the list as follows:

```
<% @passport_list.each do |passport| %>
  # passportFields
  <% passport.visas.each do |visa| %>
    <% t.fields_for :visas do |visa_fields| %>
      <%= visa_fields.text_field :visa_type %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For more information on `fields_for`, check out the link I added above, and to customize further for your use case, check out the "One-to-many" section.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should always handle the null case of an object.

Something like this if you use rails (present? is a Rails function)...

```
<% if @passport_list.present? %>
  <% @passport_list.each do |passport| %>
     passportFields
     <% passport.visas.each do |visa| %>
         <%= t.text_field :visa_type %>   
     <%end%>

  <%end%>
<% else %> 
 <p>Nothing to see here</p>
<% end %>
```

However if your @passport_list is backed by an ActiveRecord Query, you can handle this in the model/helper/controller by returning the [.none](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none) query on the model. Note that this differs from an empty array because it is an ActiveRecord Scope, so you can chain AR queries onto it

```
# scope on AR model
def self.awesomeville
  where(country_of_origin: "awesomeville")
end

# method queried in controller
@passport_list = Passport.all
if @passport_list.present? 
  @passport_list
else 
  Passport.none
end 

# additional filtering in view is now possible without fear of NoMethodError
@passport_list.awesomeville
```

Whereas a ruby Array would raise an error as it would respond to the Array methods.